# Objects and properties in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have put my questions inside the comments alongside the code below:

```
    var box = {};

    box.content = box; // box{ 'content': {} }  right?



   show('content' in box); // true because content exist inside of the box object

   show('content' in box.content); // false because box.content contains an empty object! Right?
```

Comment: Huh? This doesn't make a great deal of sense, and could be easily answered by doing some tests of your own...

Comment: `ReferenceError: show is not defined`

Comment: an endless chain of `box`-->`content`-->`box`-->`content`-->`hell`...

Comment: `box.content contains an empty object`? But you just define it as `box` so how is it empty?

Comment: i thought that it was an object within another object. So i thought the outer box contained content but that the inner box, that is the value of 'content', contained an empty object for which content did not exist.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Yes, your assertions are both correct.</strike> Actually the second one should also return true:

```
console.log('content' in box); // true
console.log('content' in box.content); // true
```

The second returns true because you're setting up recursion on this line:

```
box.content = box;
```

This is the result in the console:

[image]

Comment: My console doesn't agree

Comment: yes neither does mine. The show() functions is defined for my console and it produces true for the second show().

Comment: I dont understand why it returns true for the second output.

Comment: @DEdesigns57 because every box.content references a box, and every box has a box.content, try it in your browser

Comment: @DEdesigns57 `box` contains `content`, while `content` is `box`. So `box.content` has `box` in it while `box` having `content`. Yo dawg.

Comment: @Derek Where did `Hell` come from?

Comment: @David - The `hell` of Circular Structure.

Answer (score 0):

This should return true entirely recursively as you have a reference to the object in it's 'content' property.

```
console.log(blah.content.content.content.content === blah) //shows 'true'
```